# How to add Top3 predictions and Probability scores in different columns to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe and have used predict_proba() to get the top 3 probabilities and classes_ to get the classes as well.

I want to add these probabilities & predicted values as new columns but not sure how to go about it.

**Initial data**

```
>>> test
  Student_Id  Math  Physical  Arts
0       id_1     6         7     9
1       id_2     9         7     1
2       id_3     3         5     5
```

**Expected data**

```
Student_Id  Math  Physical  Arts Predicted_id_1 Predicted_id_2  \
0       id_1     6         7     9           id_1           id_2
1       id_2     9         7     1           id_2           id_1
2       id_3     3         5     5           id_3           id_2
  Predicted_id_3  Probability_Score_1  Probability_Score_2  \
0           id_3                  0.7                  0.3
1           id_3                  0.3                  0.7
2           id_1                  0.1                  0.3

   Probability_Score_3
0                  0.1
1                  0.1
2                  0.7
```

**Sample data and code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Ceate dataframe
data = [
    ["id_1",6,7,9],
    ["id_2",9,7,1],
    ["id_3",3,5,5],
     
]

#dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Student_Id', 'Math', 'Physical','Arts'])


#Classes from clf.Classes_
Classes = np.array(['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3'])

#Probabilities from predict_proba()
top_test_probabilities = np.array([[0.70, 0.30, 0.10], [0.30, 0.70, 0.10], [0.10, 0.30, 0.70]])

#Indices of top 3 values sorted
best_3n = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]])

#Not sure if the below helps

#find the associated id for each prediction
top_id = classes_[best_3n]

#cast to a new dataframe
top_id_df = pd.DataFrame(data=top_cat_nbr, columns = ["Predicted_id_1", "Predicted_id_2", "Predicted_id_3"])

#find the associated probability for each prediction
top_prob_score = top_test_probabilities [0][best_3n]

#cast to a new dataframe
top_prob_df = pd.DataFrame(data=top_prob_score, columns = ["Probability_Score_3", "Probability_Score_2", "Probability_Score_1"])

#Next I have to add the top_id_df and top_prob_score to test data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and concatenate the three dataframes by columns (with axis=1):
(All the indexes of the different dataframes must match (Consider performing reset_index() for each of them))

```
pd.concat([test ,top_id_df, top_prob_score], axis=1)
```